# how to instance a non-static method, that has a wired object and is from another file

Tags: java, instance

I'm having trouble calling a non-static method from an another file. My main file is called jroff.java, and the other file (which has the two methods I need) is called linkedqueue.java

In linkedqueue.java I have the following code:

```
class linkedqueue <item_t> {

   private  class node{
      item_t item;
      node link;
   }

   private  node front = null;
   private  node rear = null;

   public  boolean empty (){
      return front == null;
   }

   public void insert (item_t any) {
      node temp = new node();
      temp.item = any;
      temp.link = null;
      if(rear == null) front = temp;
              else rear.link = temp;
  rear = temp;
   }

 public item_t remove (){
      item_t value;
      if (empty ()) throw new NoSuchElementException ();
      value = front.item;
      front = front.link;
      if(front == null) return null;
                    else return value;
   }

}
```

this is how i'm trying to run insert in my main file:

```
 for (String word: words) linkedqueue.insert(word);
```

I got the file name thing right, but how exactly do I make an instance of something like this?
Here is where I use insert:

```
   String value;
   while(value != null){
       value = linkedqueue.remove().toString();
```

remove returns a item_t, and i want that in a string. the last node will have a value of null, thats when the loop should stop.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as calling a method from another file.
In Java you are defining classes and you can interact with the non-static methods of a class by creating an instance of this class with the `new` keyword.

I highly recommend either reading [Java in a Nutshell](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCwQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FJava-Nutshell-5th-David-Flanagan%2Fdp%2F0596007736&rct=j&q=java%20in%20a%20nutshell&ei=fwFFTb_yFoz2tgPguqjFCg&usg=AFQjCNEfp5Y3YP1A_Yq8JIhvgr8a2i3MUg&sig2=W34PJWspv8_3u8RlihRn9g&cad=rja) or doing the [Java tutorial](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2F&rct=j&q=java%20tutorial&ei=mwFFTa3TJIz2tgPpjLGcCg&usg=AFQjCNEOhz48O4S7xPEHp9oXa_K4M6s1lw&sig2=LlsWBJEVZItXs-jq_7ySfw&cad=rja). It will make things a lot clearer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple issues with this code:

1. The naming convention in Java is to have class names starting with a capital letter, and variables starting with a lowercase.  This is important here because it might be a source of confusion for you.
2. `linkedqueue.insert(word);` looks like a legal command, but you are in fact trying to call a non-static method on a `Class` object.  This is not possible.   You should create an instance of the class before trying this:

   ```
   linkedqueue lq = new linkedqueue();
   ```

   and then perform all of your actions on `lq`.
3. Based on your own spec, the following will throw a `NullPointerException` by design, if it ever got past a few issues:

```
     String value;
       while(value != null){
         value = linkedqueue.remove().toString();
      }
```

- a variable in a method needs to be initialized before it is used.
- if it were initialized to `null`, your body of your `while` will never execute.  Consider a `do{}while()` instead.